# If $x=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$ show that $1/a, 1/x, 1/b$ is an arithmetic progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

This is the 5th question in my assignment. It's a really freaky looking problem. I haven't come up with an answer yet but I made an attempt with the working out.
Here's the question:
If $x=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$ show that $1/a, 1/x, 1/b$ is a arithmetic progression.

Here's the working out I've done so far:
[image: working out for question 5]
I stopped there.

Answer (score 5):

First note that

$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{a+b}{ab}$$

or

$$T_1 + T_3 = 2T_2$$
$$T_3 - T_2 = T_2 - T_1$$

Answer (score 3):

If $$\ldots, a_{k - 1}, a_k, a_{k + 1}, \ldots$$ is an arithmetic progression, then
$a_k$ is the average of the term before and the term after. In our case:
$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right) .$$

Answer (score 1):

You got yourself into trouble when you computed $1/x$.  The reciprocal of $x = \dfrac{2ab}{a + b}$ is 
$$\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{a + b}{2ab}$$

Hence, 
$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{a + b}{2ab} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{a + b}{2ab} - \frac{2b}{2ab} = \cdots$$
and 
$$\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{a + b}{2ab} = \cdots$$

Comment: Can 2b/2ab be simplified to 1/a?

Comment: Yes, it can be provided $a \neq 0$, which must be true here.  However, what we need is a common denominator so we can subtract.  We obtain $$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{a + b}{2ab} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{a + b}{2ab} - \frac{2b}{2ab} = \frac{a - b}{2ab}$$  You should obtain the same answer for $$\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I just did the working out for 1/b-1/x. I got a+b/2ab

Comment: It looks like you forgot to distribute the negative. $$\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{a + b}{2ab} = \frac{2a}{2ab} - \frac{a + b}{2ab} = \frac{2a - (a + b)}{2ab} = \frac{2a - a - b}{2ab} = \frac{a - b}{2ab}$$

Comment: Oh yeah! I'm fond of doing that! I always forget to distribute negative and positive signs in problems like this. Thanks for the help!